# Feeds Import csv - inline images

Tags: 6, media, feeds

I'm using the feeds module to import thousands of nodes into my Drupal 6 site (the source is a Drupal 5 site) and after figuring a few things out, it actually works really nicely! I just have one problem though, most of these nodes are supposed to contain inline images, and I'm wondering how to recover them as they don't come with the import...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the settings of the importer (Feeds -> (Importer name ->) Processor -> Node processor -> Settings) is the Input format set to default? If so, is the default Filtered HTML? That might remove the images. You could you try changing this to Full HTML...

Answer (score 3):

If the enable full html does not work try using [Feeds Image Grabber](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber)